# My schema doesn't function as expected when inserting the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

here is my Schema code

```
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema   = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
      },
    phone:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});
```

and I am inserting the data as it is shown below (inside another file)

```
router.route('/register')
.post(function(req, res) {
    var registeration = new Registeration({
        username: req.body.username,
        phone: req.body.phone,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    registeration.save(function(err) {
        if (err){
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'That username already exists.'});
        }
        res.json({ success: true, message: 'Successfully created new user.' });
    })
});
```

The problem here is that, whenever I register new account it is successfully added even if the username already exists in my database

I set the attribute to `unique: true` but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why is your schema called `UserSchema` when the model is called `Registeration`?

Comment: @robertklep sorry I forgot to mention that the second part is inside another file, will update the question now

Comment: How do you create your model(s)? Have you checked, using the MongoDB shell, if there's a unique index for the `username` property?

Comment: @robertklep yea there is, I checked the functionality it is working and when I get the data from postman, I can see the user data successfully stored

Comment: And when you query the database using the MongoDB shell, there are multiple documents that have the same user name?

Comment: Please confirm you create registration model as `var Registeration = mongoose.model(collection_name, UserSchema);` and add it to the question if so.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes I did create the schema, the data is successfully added to the database, but the unique attribute has no effect as I can add the same username to the database without errors